# Python main data class and dependent class below (in term of physical code)

Tags: python

Let's say I have such structure with @dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass()
class Direction:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int

@dataclass_json
@dataclass()
class Movement:
    speed: int
    direction: Direction = field(default_factory=Direction)

movementDict = {'speed':2,'direction': {'x':0,'y':0,'z':1}}
movement = Movement.from_dict(movementDict)
print(movement)
```

It does what I want - transfering raw dictionary into class object. However I am forced to make Direction class on top of the file. It would be more readable if Movement class was on top of the code. Is there any way to achieve this? If I switch both these classes I get

> NameError: name 'Direction' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to create a `lambda` and pass it as the `default_factory` argument. I would also either add a `from __future__ import annotations` import at the top, or else wrap the annotation for the forward-declared class in a string, just so the compiler doesn't complain about a similar NameError in this case.

This works because the type (Direction) is only evaluated once the lambda is actually called. If you don't believe me, you can also try making an intentional typo in the name - for example like `lambda: Drection(0, 0, 0)` and will note that the code still compiles fine even though that name is not defined, as long as your input `dict` object has a value for the 'direction' key.

Here's an example to illustrate that below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


@dataclass_json
@dataclass()
class Movement:
    speed: int
    direction: 'Direction' = field(default_factory=lambda: Direction(0, 0, 0))


@dataclass_json
@dataclass()
class Direction:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int


movementDict = {'speed': 2}
movement = Movement.from_dict(movementDict)
print(movement)
```

Result:

```
Movement(speed=2, direction=Direction(x=0, y=0, z=0))
```

---

**Side note**: just adding a plug here to a very similar de-serialization library I've been working on, called the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/). It has pretty minimal dependencies, and performs a little better on average, in case anyone is curious and wants to check it out.

Comment: Thanks, it makes what I requested. There are some unwanted side effects, but I guess we will not find anything better.

Answer (score 1):

A symbol must be defined in python before it can be used. Therefore you must have defined `Direction` before it can be used in `Movement`. One option is to define `Movement` in a separate module and import `Movement` from that module. At least that way `Direction` appears to be the first thing defined in this module. It's not clear why the order in the code is important to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's just minimal reproduction example. Consider more complex situation when there is more classes like Direction (and they are ussualy treated as private). Then it's better to have such order. Me, human being reads from up to down :)

Comment: @MichałLis I would say that the order in your question is the one that makes sense - I need to know what is `Direction` in order to understand what is `Movement`. As you say, I also reading from top-down, this is why it makes sense to have the most atomic classes first and the ones using them further down...